# Can I use a 50Hz tape recorder on a 60Hz electrical system?

Tags: electrical

I have a Sony reel to reel tape player/recorder that is rated at 110V, 127V, 220V, 240V, 50Hz. Can I connect it to 110v 60Hz or do I need to purchase a 50Hz output power converter?

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine ( 60Hz running on 50 sometimes doesn't work) but if the motors are synchronous to the power grid it will run fast. Wether playback at 1.2x normal speed is a problem or not is up to you. If you are recording and playing from the same machine then it won't matter.

Grid-synchronous timing was very common decades ago (analog tv for example) - the AC frequency was stable and reliable. When devices moved to DC motors and digital control they stopped caring about the mains frequency and just generated their own timing signals.

Answer (score 1):

A transformer wont do any good. To change the frequency would probably cost more than the recorder is worth. What kind of power supply does the machine have? If it is the old style linear power supply  (has a transformer and rectifiers) then you have a problem. If it is the Switch Mode type then it will probably work ok.

Comment: A converter would probably convert AC to DC then back to AC in order to convert the frequency. A 12V battery charger and 50Hz inverter would probably work. I'm sure it would be best to hook them both up to a battery, as a bonus, you now have a UPS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no since it doesn't say 50/60Hz which would indicate it is compatible with both.

Yes you should use a transformer/converter.